# PowerBI - How to count repetitions in a column

Tags: powerbi, dax

Say I'm counting roulette spins and wish to output a chart that shows the number of occurrences that a colour is spun. E.g., if RED was drawn 3 times in a row then the chart would show 1 occurrence for 3 reds in a row.

Here is an image of a graph that is exactly what I'm looking for:

[image: Occurrence Graph]

https://roulette-simulator.info/en/roulette-analysis

This shows that in 17mil spins, there was 1 occurrence of reds being spun 27 times in a row. There were also 5 occurrences where Reds were drawn 20 times in a row. I'm trying to do this in PowerBI but struggling with counting the repetitions rather than the records.

The data I currently have looks like this (obviously time isn't accurate enough to be used as an index but should hopefully get the point across):

[image: Dataset]

Comment: I think "repetitions" might be more descriptive than "occurrences".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an index column in the query editor. Then you can use that column to find the index of the last instance where the color was *different*.

Here's how you can write that as a calculated column in DAX:

```
Repetitions =
VAR PrevColor =
    MAXX (
        FILTER (
            Roulette,
            Roulette[Index] <  EARLIER ( Roulette[Index] ) &&
            Roulette[Color] <> EARLIER ( Roulette[Color] )
        ),
        [Index]
    )
RETURN
    Roulette[Index] - PrevColor
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It helped me prep my data much better :)